# Marginalization of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, marginal-probability

An exam question asked to select **all expressions that are equal to 1, given no independence assumptions.**
The solution stated that the following expression was **not** equal to 1, but I don't understand why.
Is it possible this is a mistake?

$\sum_{a}\sum_{b}P(A=a | B=b)$

Comment: No, that is certainly not equal to $1$ in many contexts.  You may be thinking of $\sum_a\sum_b\Pr(A=a\mid B=b)\color{red}{\Pr(B=b)} = \sum_a\sum_b\Pr(A=a\color{red}{\cap}B=b)$.  Consider for trivial example the scenario where $A$ is constant and always equal to $1$ and $B$ equaling $0$ half the time and $1$ the other half the time.  You'd have $\Pr(A=1\mid B=0)=\Pr(A=1\mid B=1)=1$ and your sum would be equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $b$, the sum is $1$ since you go over all possibilities of $A$. But then you also sum over all values of $b$, which means you sum over many $1$s.

For example, suppose you throw a dice. $A$ is the value of it, $B=1$ is it is even, $0$ if odd. Then this sum should be $2$, as given even, the sum of all options of $A$ is $1$ and given odd the sum of all options of $A$ is $1$.